# Jest testing mongoose model instantiation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, mongoose, jestjs

I'm trying to test a REST API built with express and mongoose, I'm using jest and supertest for the http calls; also I'm relatively new to testing with javascript.

When testing a creation url I wan't to make sure the instantiation is called using just the req.body object but I'm not sure how to do it, after reading a lot about differences between mock objects and stubs and some of the Jest documentation my last try looks like this:

```
test('Should instantiate the model using req.body', done => {

  const postMock = jest.fn();

  const testPost = {
    name: 'Test post',
    content: 'Hello'
  };

  postMock.bind(Post); // <- Post is my model

  // I mock the save function so it doesn't use the db at all
  Post.prototype.save = jest.fn(cb => cb(null, testPost));

  // Supertest call
  request(app).post('/posts/')
  .send(testPost)
  .then(() => {
    expect(postMock.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(testPost);
    done();
  })
  .catch(err => {throw err});

});
```

Also I would like to know how to manually fail the test on the promise rejection, so it doesn't throws the `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it stands, you're performing more of a integration test rather than isolating the route handler function itself and testing just that.

First I would break away the handler for `/posts/` to its own file (assuming you haven't done this already):

`controllers/post-controller.js`

```
const Post = require('./path/to/models/post')

exports.store = async (req, res) => {
  const post = await new Post(req.body).save()
  res.json({ data: post }
}
```

Next simply use the handler wherever you defined your routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const postController = require('./path/to/controllers/post-controller')

app.post('/posts', postController.store)
```

With this abstraction we can now isolate our `postController.store` and test that it works with `req.body`. Now since we need to mock mongoose to avoid hitting an actual database, you can create a mocked `Post` like so (using the code you already have):

`path/to/models/__mocks__/post.js`

```
const post = require('../post')

const mockedPost = jest.fn()
mockedPost.bind(Post)

const testPost = {
  name: 'Test post',
  content: 'Hello'
}


Post.prototype.save = jest.fn(cb => {
  if (typeof cb === 'function') {
    if (process.env.FORCE_FAIL === 'true') {
      process.nextTick(cb(new Error(), null))
    } else {
      process.nextTick(cb(null, testPost))
    }
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (process.env.FORCE_FAIL === 'true') {
        reject(new Error())
      } else {
        resolve(testPost)
      }
    })
  }
})

module.exports = mockedPost
```

Notice the check for `process.env.FORCE_FAIL` if for whatever reason you wanted to fail it.

Now we're ready to test that using the `req.body` works:

`post-controller.test.js`

```
// Loads anything contained in `models/__mocks__` folder
jest.mock('../location/to/models')

const postController = require('../location/to/controllers/post-controller')

describe('controllers.Post', () => {
  /**
   * Mocked Express Request object.
   */
  let req

  /**
   * Mocked Express Response object.
   */
  let res

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      body: {}
    }
    res = {
      data: null,
      json(payload) {
        this.data = JSON.stringify(payload)
      }
    }
  })

  describe('.store()', () => {
    test('should create a new post', async () => {
      req.body = { ... }
      await postController(req, res)
      expect(res.data).toBeDefined()

      ...
    })

    test('fails creating a post', () => {
      process.env.FORCE_FAIL = true
      req.body = { ... }

      try {
        await postController.store(req, res)
      } catch (error) {
        expect(res.data).not.toBeDefined()

        ...
      }
    })

  })
})
```

This code is untested, but I hope it helps in your testing.